# Navigation Bar Items after push from SwiftUI to UIKit

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI `NavigationView` in which I push to a to `UIViewControllerRepresentable` conforming `UIViewController`. The navigation view naturally adds its back button. However, all navigation bar buttons that I set in the pushed-to view controller are also gone.

The code for adding the item is nothing new and works just fine if I push from a good ol' UIKit View Controller:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(filterItemTapped(button:)))
```

My theory is that they haven't wired up bridging between NavigationView and UIViewController's navigation items, but maybe somebody knows a workaround.

Comment: Clarification question (which may mean you need to add more code to reproduce): `UIViewControllerRelatable` is a `View` inside a `SwiftUI` app. As is your `NavigationView`. But you make it sound like you want some kind of navigation bar in your `UIViewController`, as in `UIKit`? If so, maybe you need to rethink something - maybe even the reverse (put your SwiftUI `View` into your `UIKit` app).

Comment: Final thoughts. If you want to "push" values/data into your `UIViewController`, that's more `Combine` than `SwiftUI` (but yeah, it's both). But if you want to push a `NavigationBar`, which is a `View`, then **yes** you need to do the reverse - make a `UIKit` app and import the views.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to have a SwiftUI View with its native bar buttons and a UIKit ViewController with its own native bar buttons in the same App. But your answer made me understand that that's not possible.

What I ended up doing is to wrap my UIViewController in a SwiftUI View and set those bar buttons on it. Works like a charm. So thanks man.

Comment: Here is solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66224181/14733292

Answer (score 0):

This is simple approach I just used that is working really well. Essentially it boils down to just adding the navigation items in SwiftUI where the wrapped UIKit view is used.

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: destinationView(),
            label: {
                Text("Go to MyUIKitView")
            }
        )
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func destinationView() -> some View {
        MyUIKitView()
            .navigationTitle("Your Title")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button(
                        action: { 
                            // Do something here
                        },
                        label: { Image(systemName: "camera") }
                    )
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

In your `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, wrap your `UIViewController` with a `UINavigationController`.

```swift
struct CustomUIViewControllerRepresentation: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UINavigationController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let viewController = CustomUIViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        return navigationController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {

    }
}
```