# Navigation Bar Items not shown when UIKit > SwiftUI > UIKit

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

When pushing from a SwiftUI view to a UIKit, navigation bar items are not present or not added.

I have added one item in the storyboard and one item in code, neither show up.

This is possibly a bug in SwiftUI, but I feel like this is probably a pretty common case and perhaps I am missing something?

There is some overlap with this question: [Navigation Bar Items after push from SwiftUI to UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124602/navigation-bar-items-after-push-from-swiftui-to-uikit) although I am not sure if they are the same or not

### Results

[image: Gif of simulator]

### Inputs

[image: Storyboard]

1. No code, Storyboard only
2. No code, Storyboard only
3. 

```
class MyHostingController: UIHostingController<SwiftUIView> {
 
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {    
        super.init(coder: aDecoder, rootView: SwiftUIView())
    }
}
```

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: MyUIKitView(),
            label: {
                Text("Go to MyUIKitView")
            })
    }
}
```

Glue between 3 & 4

```
struct MyUIKitView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = MyUIKitViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyUIKitViewController {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let myVC = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MyUIKitViewController") as! MyUIKitViewController
        return myVC
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyUIKitViewController, context: Context) {
        print("♻️")
    }
}
```

4. 

```
class MyUIKitViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //  ADD NAV BUTTON HERE  
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .camera))
    }
}
```

5. No code, Storyboard only

Answer (score 22, accepted):

SwiftUI view used its own navigation controller and it ignores the UIKit navigation controller so the possible solution is to set your navigation bar to parent controller and set your navigation bar element by coding.

like this

```
class MyUIKitViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //  ADD NAV BUTTON HERE - must be in DispatchQueue
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.parent?.navigationItem.title = "Your Title"
            self.parent?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .camera))
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution is to use `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?`. This is the exact same as above. It gives a topItem.

```
class MyUIKitViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //  ADD NAV BUTTON HERE - must be in DispatchQueue
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Your Title"
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItems?.append(UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .camera))
        }
    }
}
```

**I used DispatchQueue for when the view is initiated then the parent is not set at this time**. (You can use also use `viewWillAppear` instead of `DispatchQueue.main.async`)

************Edit************

If you don't want to add elements programmatically and if you need to use the same element from the storyboard then you can use this approch.

```
class MyUIKitViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //  ADD NAV BUTTON HERE
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .camera))
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { //<--Here
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = self.navigationItem.title
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItems = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I edited your answer a bit just because I didn't notice the DispatchMain bit and I thought it wasn't working. I will award bounty after the 16 hours is up!

Comment: This is the code that I used: ```DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.parent?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(self.addPhoto(_:)))
        }```

Comment: Thanks! Helped a ton.  My UIKit view that wasn't showing the buttons is sometimes shown from UIKit -> UIKit and sometimes from UIKit-SwiftUI-UIKit so had to do some conditional logic as well to detect the correct type of the previous view (UIViewController vs. UIHostingController) and use the appropriate `navigationItem`

Comment: Hi Mark do you have a demo project for UIKit-SwiftUI-UIKit. I am struggling with the navigation bar .. The navigation item gets lost once I switch from UIKit > SwiftUI

Comment: and how to customize navigation title color?

Comment: in my case in the following code `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItems?.append`

`rightBarButtonItems` was nil

so, instead I used:
`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .camera)`

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and possibly a more SwiftUI-centric approach I just used that is working really well. And it has the bonus of not having to do any awkward `DispatchQueue` work or to modify your existing code in the `UIViewController`.

Just FYI, in my case, this `SwiftUIView` is used inside a `NavigationStack`, so the navigation is owned by SwiftUI. The other answers might work better when the opposite is true (i.e., pushing `SwiftUIView` onto the stack in a `UINavigationController`).

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: ,
            label: {
                Text("Go to MyUIKitView")
            }
        )
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func destinationView() -> some View {
        MyUIKitView()
            .navigationTitle("Your Title")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button(
                        action: { 
                            // Do something here
                        },
                        label: { Image(systemName: "camera") }
                    )
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think perhaps this should be an answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124602/navigation-bar-items-after-push-from-swiftui-to-uikit?noredirect=1&lq=1 and not here?

Comment: Yeah, maybe a more precise answer for there. I'll add it there -- thanks for the suggestion.