# Connecting UIKit with SwiftUI, why did I lose my NavBar?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

So when I use the old UIKit Lifecycle with `SceneDelegate` and `AppDelegate` I get the desired result. But when I use the new `App` life cycle I can't figure out to get the NavBar back..

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DiffableContainer()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DiffableContainer()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}


struct DiffableContainer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: DiffableTableVC())
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}

class DiffableTableVC: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.backgroundColor = .green
        navigationItem.title = "Test"
        title = "Hello"
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate  {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        print("This is set up and running")
        return true
    }
}
```

Here is the lifecycle that I am using now:

```
  @main
    struct ContactsApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `NavigationView` that SwiftUI provides?

Comment: @Rengers Well I wanted to keep the NavBar customization all in one place, also curious if there was a way to get it done.

Comment: Might be helpfull : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186411/navigation-bar-items-not-shown-when-uikit-swiftui-uikit